# MySQL: How to get top 10 and remaining?

Tags: mysql, pagination, sql-order-by, limit

In MySQL to get the 10 top you use LIMIT right?

Like this... (please correct my syntax if it's wrong)

```
SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

How do I get the 11th row and the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an offset parameter, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10, 999999
```

I put 999999 because you have to specify the limit value, and I'm hoping there's no more rows than that. You can always add a bigger number.

EDIT

But why don't you just take all the results and then just split them into two arrays (first 10 and the rest)?

Comment: Can you arrange objects in an array? How do I do that?

Comment: It'll rely on another language such as PHP

Comment: You can do it with objects only, it's the same principle. You can also return results as an array. Whatever you prefer. What language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the offset to limit as well as the number of values you like to have.

```
SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10,1000000000;
```